# Maximum Depth Limit Exceeded during route protection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in this code ??
I am protecting the route but the error is comming  .
I have creted a ProtectionRoute component  which calls AUTH_FUNC(Checks whether user is locked in or not) from the TwitterState.js and if the user is logged in then the ProtectionRoute returns the Component and else redirect to the login page !

**App.js**

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router , Routes , Route , useNavigate} from "react-router-dom"
import Home from "./pages/Home"
import Auth from "./pages/Auth"
import Profile from "./pages/Profile"
import Bookmark from "./pages/Bookmark"
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound"
import Explore from "./pages/Explore"
import TrendingTags from "./pages/TrendingTags"
import Discover from "./pages/Discover"
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import Register from "./pages/Register"
import EditProfile from "./pages/EditProfile"
import ProtectedRoute from "./components/ProtectedRoute"

function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
      <ToastContainer />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<ProtectedRoute><Home/></ProtectedRoute>}/>
        <Route path="/auth" element={<ProtectedRoute><Auth/></ProtectedRoute>}/>
        <Route path="/profile" element={<ProtectedRoute><Profile/></ProtectedRoute>}  />
        <Route path="/message" element={<ProtectedRoute><NotFound/></ProtectedRoute>}  />
        <Route path="/notifications" element={<ProtectedRoute><NotFound/></ProtectedRoute>}  />
        <Route path="/bookmark" element={<ProtectedRoute><Bookmark/></ProtectedRoute>}  />
        <Route path="/explore" element={<ProtectedRoute><Explore/></ProtectedRoute>}  />
        <Route path="/explore/trending/:tagName" element={<ProtectedRoute><TrendingTags/></ProtectedRoute>}  />
        <Route path="/discover" element={<ProtectedRoute><Discover/></ProtectedRoute>}  />
        <Route path="/register" element={<ProtectedRoute><Register /></ProtectedRoute>}  />
        <Route path="/profile/edit" element={<ProtectedRoute><EditProfile /></ProtectedRoute>}  />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**ProtectedRoute.js**

```
import React , {useContext} from "react";
import { Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import TwitterContext from "../context/TwitterContext";

export default function ProtectedRoute ({children}) {
    const {AUTH_FUNC} = useContext(TwitterContext)
    const loggedin = AUTH_FUNC()
    if(!loggedin){
        return <Navigate to="/auth"/>
    }
    return children
};
```

**Twitter.jsx**

```
import TwitterContext from "./TwitterContext";

const TwitterState = (props) => {
    const AUTH_FUNC = () =>{
        const res = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("UserData"))
        if(res !== null){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    return <TwitterContext.Provider value={{AUTH_FUNC}}>
        {props.children}
    </TwitterContext.Provider>
}

export default TwitterState
```

Error :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You are protecting the `"/auth"` route as well, which when a user is not authenticated yet will create a navigation loop from `"/auth"` to `"/auth"`, repeat ad nauseam.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ToastContainer />
      <Routes>
        ...
        <Route path="/auth" element={<ProtectedRoute><Auth/></ProtectedRoute>}/>
        ...
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

```
export default function ProtectedRoute ({ children }) {
  const { AUTH_FUNC } = useContext(TwitterContext);
  const loggedin = AUTH_FUNC();
  if (!loggedin) {
    return <Navigate to="/auth"/>;
  }
  return children;
};
```

## Solution

You don't want to protect the authentication route the same way as the routes that require authentication. Remove `ProtectedRoute` from the `"/auth"` route.

Refactor the `ProtectedRoute` to render an `Outlet` also so you can make the code more ***DRY***. This allows the `ProtectedRoute` component to wrap entire sets of routes that need to be protected.

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function ProtectedRoute () {
  const { AUTH_FUNC } = useContext(TwitterContext);
  const loggedin = AUTH_FUNC();

  if (loggedin === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return loggedin
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/auth" replace />;
};
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ToastContainer />
      <Routes>
        {/* Unprotected routes */}
        <Route path="/auth" element={<Auth />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />

        {/* Protected routes */}
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
          <Route path="/message" element={<NotFound />} />
          <Route path="/notifications" element={<NotFound />} />
          <Route path="/bookmark" element={<Bookmark />} />
          <Route path="/explore" element={<Explore />} />
          <Route path="/explore/trending/:tagName" element={<TrendingTags />}  />
          <Route path="/discover" element={<Discover />} />
          <Route path="/profile/edit" element={<EditProfile />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

It's also a common pattern to protect the "anonymous" routes from authenticated users. For this create another protected route component that does the inverse of the `ProtectedRoute` component.

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function AnonymousRoute () {
  const { AUTH_FUNC } = useContext(TwitterContext);
  const loggedin = AUTH_FUNC();

  if (loggedin === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return loggedin
    ? <Navigate to="/" replace />
    : <Outlet />;
};
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ToastContainer />
      <Routes>
        {/* Anonymous routes */}
        <Route element={<AnonymousRoute />}>
          <Route path="/auth" element={<Auth />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        </Route>

        {/* Protected routes */}
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
          <Route path="/message" element={<NotFound />} />
          <Route path="/notifications" element={<NotFound />} />
          <Route path="/bookmark" element={<Bookmark />} />
          <Route path="/explore" element={<Explore />} />
          <Route path="/explore/trending/:tagName" element={<TrendingTags />}  />
          <Route path="/discover" element={<Discover />} />
          <Route path="/profile/edit" element={<EditProfile />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Auth` is in protected route and causes the navigation loop.

```js
<Route path="/auth" element={<ProtectedRoute><Auth/></ProtectedRoute>}/>

export default function ProtectedRoute ({children}) {
    const {AUTH_FUNC} = useContext(TwitterContext)
    const loggedin = AUTH_FUNC()
    if(!loggedin){
        return <Navigate to="/auth"/> 
    }
    return children
};
```

`/auth` route probably shouldn't be a protected route, in order to function normally.